# JetBrains IDE - Git Login Credentials Dialog Disable

Tags: git, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, goland

I am using JetBrains IDEs but I would not like it to use my credentials for any Git operations. Git commands are run through the terminal periodically, and annoyingly, a popup will appear to ask for my credentials.

How can I disable the popup?

[image: jetbrains-ide-git-credentials-popup]

Suppress popup message.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution can be caching the git credentials by utilising the `git-credential-cache` helper to store passwords temporarily.

For example in your terminal itself, run this once: `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'` and restart the IDE.

Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache#_examples

Secondly since you are using the IDE, have you tried using this?

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html#set-passwords-for-git-remotes

Additionally, using SSH keys is another way to avoid password based login IMHO.